# Installed rails_admin and everything stops working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

So i wanted to create an app, where people can view art. The problem is, only the admin should be able to create, edit and delete data. So i wanted to add an admin interface. I went with the rails_admin gem.

I've installed everything as it said on the git documentation, but everything stopped working when I installed it. I can't generate scaffolds, models or controllers and I can't start my server. It gives me this message whenever I try something.

```
/Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant Admin (NameError)
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise.rb:256:in `get'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise.rb:290:in `new'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise.rb:290:in `add_mapping'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block in devise_for'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `each'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
from /Users/Max/Desktop/walls/config/routes.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
from /Users/Max/Desktop/walls/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/Max/Desktop/walls/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Max/Desktop/walls/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /Users/Max/Desktop/walls/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /Users/Max/Desktop/walls/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/Max/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I already had all my data set up before I installed rails_admin, so it would be pretty bad if I had to start over.

If someone needs more info, I'd be glad to give it, but I have no idea what to post right now.

Comment: there isn't one, maybe that's the problem

Comment: I had the same error, when some of my models had an assosiation with nonexistent model. I had removed all this assisiations, and everything became good. In your case nonexistent model is Admin model&

Answer (score 1):

Look at your routes.rb, there must me some code like this
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

remove it or delete it. You have already remove the admin but may haven't modify in routes.

Answer (score 0):

To get back to a working project state again, remove the gem 'rails_admin' declaration from your Gemfile, remove the rails_admin.rb file from your config/initializers directory and then remove the rails_admin generated route from config/routes.rb:

```
devise_for :admins
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/rails_admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

That is what is causing Devise to look for an Admin model.
Removing that, along with removing the gem and initializer file should remove the whole thing from your project.