# rails_admin breaks everything, uninitialized constant Admin (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-admin

## What I try to archieve

I am writing a rails app that is mostly CRUD. I want to have an admin interface so that non-programmers should be able to control the content. I decided to go with the ready-made library [rails admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin), because it seems to be the one that offers the most of convention > configuration.

## What goes wrong

Well, mostly everything.

Everytime I run a command that uses the rails configuration (it seems) it halts and gives me a long error. The errors I get in my shells [are posted here](http://pastie.org/private/qsccdnb8m0pycv2i2vtq2a) if you can understand it better than I do.

If I do another rails command, such as `rails g model Admin` it fails in the same manner, complaining `uninitialized constant Admin (NameError)`.

[This is my Gemfile](http://pastie.org/private/0khunhucfsdwpdcw7gggog).

## How it got this bad

I was strolling along, whistling and having a jolly time. Created a ruby application, installed Devise and set up the User class with it, scaffolded a few CRUD MVC's, made a few custom controllers-views. I know that the gem 'will_paginate' is in conflict with 'rails_admin', so I removed it from my gemfile and instead went with 'kaminari'.

## Who I suspect

[Erik](https://github.com/sferik). No, I'm sure he's great. But rails_admin obviously did not play nice with my app. I suspect this has something to do with me not creating an 'Admin' model before installing the gem. But I can't fix it now, since I get theese errors (and I get errors even if I remove rails_admin from the gemfile, do a `bundle` and then try to `rails g`).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383367/installed-rails-admin-and-everything-stops-working

Comment: The difference is that he could set up a new model, something that does not work in my case.

Comment: Don't know how to fix this, but to remove these errors, in addition to removing the gem, you will also have to remove the initializer that is part of the rails_admin installation. Should be in `config/initalizers/rails_admin.rb`.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this did not help. I did `rm config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` and the file was removed. Then I commented the line with the rails_admin lib in my Gemfile. Then I did `$bundle && rails s`, but still got the same results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you removed the rails_admin generated route from config/routes.rb:

```
devise_for :admins
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/rails_admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
```

That is what is causing Devise to look for an Admin model.
Removing that, along with removing the gem and initializer file should remove the whole thing from your project.